# how to create a group on openfire from coding in android

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I had created a small chat application using smack api,XMPP,openfire and i want to make a facility of group chat.
I can able to create a group on openfire from wizard throw,but i want to create a group in openfire from coding in android.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [the smack documentation](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html) you can create a new group chat ie room as follow:

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(conn1, "myroom@conference.jabber.org");
muc.create("testbot");
muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
```

And if you are referring to group in user contact list then you can also do it as follows:

```
roster.createGroup("groupName");
```

Where `roster` is the reference to the roster list of logged in user.